# Measure that is translation invariant but not invariant to negation

Tags: measure-theory

Does a measure $\mu: \mathscr{B}^1\to[0,\infty]$ (where $\mathscr{B}^1$ is the Borel sigma-algebra) that is translation invariant (i.e. $\mu(x)=\mu(c+x)$) but not invariant under $t:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, t(x)=-x$ exist? If yes, what value does it assign to the unit interval?

Edit: As @GEdgar has pointed out, this measure will not be locally finite, so $\mu([0,1])$ will be $\infty$.

Edit edit: I was given the hint to construct a Borel set $C\subseteq [0,1]$ such that for every sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_n$ it holds that $-C=t(C)\nsubseteq \bigcup_{n\geq0} (a_n + C)$.
Define $\mu: \mathscr{B}^1\to\mathbb{R}$  such that $$\mu(A)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{$\exists$ real sequence $(a_n)_n$ with $A\subseteq\bigcup_{n\geq 0}(a_n+C)$}\\ \infty &\text{else}\end{cases}$$
Additional hint: For $C$ take the set of $x\in[0,1]$ that can be written as $x=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x_n}{4^n}$ where $x_n\in\{0,1,3\}$.

Comment: A locally finite measure, no.  Translation invariance is enough to get Haar measure, and that is invariant under negation as well.  So we are left to consider a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(U) = +\infty$ for all nonempty open sets.  So the second answer is $\mu([0,1]) = +\infty$.  But I have not answered the first question.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you, see my edit.

Comment: Are you positive that the $C$ given above in the hint works? I'm under the impression that this cannot work for any countable set, as you can just construct the sequence of $a_n$ based on the set itself (there's only countably many elements to cover, after all).

Comment: @varpi: The proposed C in the hint is uncountable.

Comment: newb question: Is [0,∞] the codomain of ? And why is it closed at infinity? because of its intended countability?